# Traversing a nested 'ul' and saving data through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to save the data in the nested ul.I want to first check the depth level then go from the top and save every ul seperately with the position . This is so when I am retrieving data from the database I know where to append which ul etc. Can someone kindly please go through the code and tell me if my approach is correct.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="start">
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>1.1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>1.2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>1.2.1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>1.2.2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>1.2.2.1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>1.3</li>
</ul>
```

```js
function myf() {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var c = document.getElementById("start");
    var x = c.getElementsByTagName("UL").length;

    for (j = 0; j < x; j++) {
      var position = i + "_" + j; // here actually what I want to save is the depth level and the child node index 

      var y = c.getElementsByTagName("UL")[j];
      var name = y.getElementsByTagName("LI")[0];

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "{% url 'save_data' %}",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
            "position": position,
            "Name": name
          },
          async: false,
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: FYI that's not a nested `ul`

Comment: How do I go about this ? Please help

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do. If you want to save the data in the `ul` elements I'd suggest creating a data structure from them and then convert that to JSON and send it to your server to be saved. You would need to fix the HTML first for that to work, though

Comment: i created these by appending , so I thought it is nested

Comment: How do I create the data structure and how I do save these ul s in a way I can understand what comes under what .